# Como passar dados de uma tabela para um relátório em PDF usando React e JSPDF?

Tags: react, relatório, jspdf

Segue meu código:

```
exportar = () => {
        var doc = new jsPDF()
        var d = new Date();
        var texto = "Generator PDF"
        var mes = d.getMonth() + 1;
        doc.setFont('times', 'bold')
        doc.setFontSize(14)
        doc.text(10, 10, texto);
        doc.output('dataurlnewwindow', 'Clientes_'+d.getDate()+'/'+mes+'/'+d.getFullYear()+'.pdf')
    }
```

Do jeito que está gera um arquivo PDF com o valor da variável texto, mas preciso saber como faço para passar os dados da tabela para esse relatório.

Antes que me falem para ir na documentação do JSPDF eu aviso que já fui e não localizei nada do tipo.

Comment: Olá o objetivo é gerar uma PDF com os dados que estão numa tabela? Porque não usas o PDF-AutoTable? https://simonbengtsson.github.io/jsPDF-AutoTable/#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa a biblioteca jsPDf-AutoTable. Basta recuperar sua table html e passar para a biblioteca que ela irá exportar o arquivo pdf da sua tabela.

```
var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
var elem = document.getElementById("basic-table");
var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(elem);
doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data);
doc.save("table.pdf");
```